# infix notation sometimes doesn't work in scala, why is that?

Tags: list, scala

Alright, so I was making some tests to get familiar with Scala, and wanted to see if I could make lists Java style rather than the fancy way you'd do it in Scala...

I know that you can do it like this: `val lst = List.range(0, 100, 1)` but I just wanted to see what java style would look like in scala

Alright so here's what I did:

```
var lst = List[Int]()

for(i <- 0 until 100) {
    lst = lst :: i // here's where it complains
}
```

for some reason scala, or at least the scala ide for eclipse doesn't like that I append using infix notation, a-la `lst :: i` it wants me to do it like this: `lst.::(i)` otherwise it says `::` isn't defined or something, it's not the first time it's happened either...

so can anyone here explain why it does that, or is it just a case of bad implementation in eclipse and thus something I have to live with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scala, a `List` is of immutable length. It can work like a `LIFO` (last in, first out) structure, but it cannot behave like a Java `ArrayList`.

You are doing this:

```
val lst = List[Int]()
```

which gives your `lst` a size of `0`. It means you can't really do anything with it.

For a mutable collection, use `ListBuffer`.

Also, the `::` operator is right associative, which means it will be called on the object found on the right side of the operator.

```
val lst = ListBuffer[Int]()

for (i <- 0 until 100) {
    lst += i // will add to the tail.
}
```

Comment: alright, that cleared some things up... Strange how a mutable value is still immutable because it's a list...

Comment: uh, sure you can do something with a list of size zero.  you could prepend something to it.  there is no reason to use a mutable collection!  And if you are going to use a mutable collection, you should be able to use a val instead of a var.

Comment: `ListBuffer` tends to be a little slower that using `List` and reversing, though it depends on details of optimization; if the JIT compiler gets everything right it will be faster, but it's more easily confused.  Using `List.newBuilder[Int]` as your starting point and adding to that is consistently the fastest way to create a list in the opposite-from-natural order.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a problem with infix notation.  Rather, it's because method names ending with `:` are applied as

```
a ??: b
b.??:(a)
```

So you simply have your arguments backwards.

```
lst = i :: lst
```

will work fine.

(Of course, you then have the issue that lists act like stacks, so you need to push the numbers on in reverse order.)

Comment: yeah but then i will be added at the head of the list, not at the tail, which isn't exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Then, you can do this operation in reverse order: `for (i <- (0 to 100) reverse) ...` (reverse is constant time operation for ranges) or use ListBuffer as @alex23 proposed

Comment: @alex23 Not _quite_. Well, conceptually that's the case. But since Lists are immutable creating a new list doesn't require copying the old one, which seems to be what you were implying.

Comment: @Cubic actually it is property of [*persistent* data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure), not *immutable* by itself

Comment: @om-nom-nom Apparently my comment implies that immutable data structures are always persistent. I apologize for the confusion, of course that's not the case.